# Why TypeScript compiler does not give error when function returns undefined while function's return type is number?

Tags: typescript, function, types, return

Why TSC does not give error when function returns `null` or `undefined` while function's return type is `number`.

```
//gives error
//Error : A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)
function add1(a: number, b: number): number {}


// no error
function add2(a: number, b: number): number {
  return undefined;
}

// no error
function add3(a: number, b: number): number {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I get `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)` as expected

Comment: enable strict flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no error when Type Checking compiler option `strictNullChecks` is `off`. Enabling the option will result in Typescript displaying the error for the functions `add2` and `add3`.

You can read more about it: [strictnullchecks-off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-off) and [strictnullchecks-on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-on)

Answer (score 1):

add "strict":true under "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 0):

as @S.M mentioned above it is caused by `strict` flag indeed it is caused by `strictNullChecks` flag.

when  I set

```
"strict": true,
```

or

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

TSC gives error as what I expect